# How to create custom shipping charge module

Tags: shipping

I want a create a module for shipping charge where shipping charge gets calculated as per my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are following   tutorial to how to `Create a Custom Shipping Method in Magento`

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-magento--cms-23747

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/